Loan/depo pricing consequences of IBOR transition
Regulators phase out the use of surveyed IBOR rates in favour of overnight indexes calculated from actual collateralized transactions (ESTR, SOFR…). These have no variety of periods, only 1 rate. IBOR rates had 1M, 3M, 6M… Thus there is a 1Y gap between the o/n base rate and the first liquid IRS of 1Y tenor. The yield curve from o/n all the way to the back end of the swap curve is the basis for loan/depo pricing. What are the practical loan/depo valuation consequences of dropping the short end tenor periods? Please assume no liquid term futures on the o/n rate exist.
Many thanks!
Ivan

first off estr is not collateralised. second there exist liquid short dated swaps (i.e. with tenors <1y, for eg: 3mo or 5mo swaps) or even central bank data FF/ECB/BOE swaps for example.

data should read "dated" in the above, but can't amend it.

Are you looking at the MosPrime to RUONIA transition?

@user68819 Thank you, so the answer in general terms is that the short end of the curve can always be filled in by derivative instruments. If IBOR cash rates are abandoned, short tenor fix leg / o/n float leg swaps can take their place. Yes? DimitriVulis: The question was asked in general terms, but if you can answer with experience from a particular currency case, it will be very valuable to me. Thank you :-)

Yes in most markets which are developed that's the case.
